The angle between u and v looks smaller than 90 degree but the dot product is still negative.
Screenshot of u and v graph
Help

The scale of x-axis and y-axis doesn't correspond.
1 unit in the direction of x is much bigger than 1 unit in the direction of y. If you rescale them, the angle would look obtuse.
